# How to point to value of variable

Tags: python, variables

To avoid writing a long, ugly ternary a dozen times, such as `p_count = root.pool_count if hasattr(root, 'pool_count') else (-1)`, I wrote the **GetThis(el, attr, err="")** function.

How do I get the function to concatenate the **values** of *el* & *attr* into an element, instead of *attr* as a literal?

```
test_data = ("""
    <rsp stat="ok">
        <group id="34427465497@N01" iconserver="1" iconfarm="1" lang="" ispoolmoderated="0" is_member="0" is_moderator="0" is_admin="0">
            <name>GNEverybody</name>
            <members>245</members>
            <pool_count>133</pool_count>
            <topic_count>106</topic_count>
            <restrictions photos_ok="1" videos_ok="1" images_ok="1" screens_ok="1" art_ok="1" safe_ok="1" moderate_ok="0" restricted_ok="0" has_geo="0" />
        </group>
    </rsp>
""")
    ################

from lxml import etree
from lxml import objectify
    ################

def GetThis(el, attr, err=""):
    if hasattr(el, attr):
        return el.attr
    else:
        return err
    ################

Grp = objectify.fromstring(test_data)
root = Grp.group

gName   = GetThis(root, "name", "No Name")
err_tst = GetThis(root, "not-there", "Error OK")
p_count = root.pool_count if hasattr(root, 'pool_count') else (-1)
```

As it is, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Mirc/Python/Temp Files/test_lxml.py", line 108, in <module>
        gName  = GetThis(root, "name", "")
    File "C:/Mirc/Python/Temp Files/test_lxml.py", line 10, in GetThis
        print (el.attr)
    File "lxml.objectify.pyx", line 218, in lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement.__getattr__ (src\lxml\lxml.objectify.c:3506)
    File "lxml.objectify.pyx", line 437, in lxml.objectify._lookupChildOrRaise (src\lxml\lxml.objectify.c:5756)
AttributeError: no such child: attr
```

Thank you!

Comment: isn't `root = Grp.group` supposed to be `root = Grp.group()`??

Comment: You mean, like `getattr(el, attr)`? In fact, `getattr` does exactly what you want, including a default value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `GetThis` function is not needed since you can simply use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
gName   = getattr(root, "name", "No Name")
err_tst = getattr(root, "not-there", "Error OK")
```

The first argument is the object, the second is the attribute, and the third, which is optional, is a default value to return if the attribute doesn't exist (if this last part is omitted, an `AttributeError` is raised instead).

The two lines of code above are equivalent to these:

```
gName   = root.name if hasattr(root, "name") else "No Name"
err_tst = root.not-there if hasattr(root, "not-there") else "Error OK"
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a function called getattr(foo,"bar") which return the value of the bar attr of the foo object. Just read the doc ..

Comment: Exactly.  That is what I said 5 minutes ago.